# webpack babel loader imports same module twice

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm creating a component library that consists of several ES2015 modules. Each is relatively self contained, but there's an outer build system to help facilitate integration testing and deployments.
One of the modules has a core module and a set of optional submodules. The code structure looks loosely like:

```
root
  .\build\...
  .\src
    .\bundle1
      .\build\...
      .\src
        .\core.js
        .\submodules\
          .\a.js
          .\b.js
```

Due to historical reasons, a few of the submodules depend on the core module and, for the moment, must be deployed with it, so there ends up being a bit of a circular dependency. As mentioned earlier, each module is relatively self-contained, so it has its own build system. When the local build is used, everything appears fine. The problem becomes apparent when the "master" build system is ued. When it kicks off the same build, the core chunk ends up getting generated twice. The internal submodules attach themselves to the first instance, but the second instance is actually exported, rendering the whole house of cards pretty useless.
This doesn't appear to be a webpack issue, as when I was creating the demo app I wasn't using babel, and the bug did not appear.

Apologies for taking so long to get to the point... **My question is**, is there anything obvious that I'm missing that could be causing this, or is there a bug somewhere in babel / webpack-babel-loader?

Since it's a bit complicated I created [this reference project](https://github.com/ccamarat/webpack-babel-loader-circular-reference-bug/tree/feature/add_babel) instead of inlining the source here. As mentioned above, /develop doesn't exhibit this problem since it's not using babel. The add-babel branch does.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that, yes, I did miss something that probably should have been obvious. Since `bundle1`'s config is opened from several levels higher it apparently needs a [context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html). TBH I'm not sure I fully grok this, given it works when commonJS is used but not when transpiled...

Comment: The link tells that a context is used when a dynamic import is involved.

Comment: True. In this case my problem was I didn't know `context` was a configuration option. I blame WebPack's godawful documentation :p